# How to allocate RAM pages in Windows without initialization?

Tags: memory-management

I would like to use more than 4 GB in a 32 bit process, so my approach is to lock a bunch of physical pages. Later I map them into the virtual address space chunk by chunk as needed. It seems as I am forced to use VirtualAlloc. This function initializes my pages with zeros and with that burning a huge amount of machine cycles.

Isn't there a faster way?

Comment: Yes, by using a 64-bit process :)

Comment: Why do you need to do this in a 32-bit process?

Comment: Huh? Are you sure that a 64 bit process would improve the speed? When you allocate some memory in a 64 bit process on the standard way Windows still locks a bunch of physical pages, allocates virtual pages (and when doing so initializes them with zeros) and then maps the physical pages to the virtual pages. Even for the initialization probably the same instruction is used (store string and no 32 bit instructions nor 64 bit instructions).